# Middle point in line

Tags: objective-c, opengl, mouseevent

### Introduction:

I register mouse events (mouseDragged, mouseDown) and convert their location to NSValue after some corrections. After that they are being added to NSMutableArray and later on they are taken back, converted back to CGPoint, added to GLFloat (vertex array) and drawn via OpenGL. But when mouse drag is done faster than objective-c can register events, there appears big spacings between points. I need to correct that.

### More about my code:

Mouse event location point is being edited after registering it, to make 4 points from him, to draw glQuad later. It looks something like this:

```
locationPoint = [self convertPoint: [event locationInWindow] fromView:self];

//Top left corner of quad
quadTopLeftCorner.x = locationPoint.x - someFloatValue;
quadTopLeftCorner.y = locationPoint.y + someFloatValue;
//Top right corner of quad
quadTopRightCorner.x = locationPoint.x + someFloatValue;
quadTopRightCorner.y = locationPoint.y + someFloatValue;
//Bottom left corner of quad
quadBottomLeftCorner.x = locationPoint.x - someFloatValue;
quadBottomLeftCorner.y = locationPoint.y - someFloatValue;
//Bottom right corner of quad
quadBottomRightCorner.x = locationPoint.x + someFloatValue;
quadBottomRightCorner.y = locationPoint.y - someFloatValue;
```

And they are being converted to NSValue and moved to NSMutableArray

```
someNSValueTopLeft = [NSValue valueWithPoint:quadTopLeftCorner];
someNSValueTopRight = [NSValue valueWithPoint:quadTopRightCorner];
someNSValueBottomLeft = [NSValue valueWithPoint:quadBottomLeftCorner];
someNSValueBottomRight = [NSValue valueWithPoint:quadBottomRightCorner];

[someNSMutableArray addObject:someNSValueTopLeft];
[someNSMutableArray addObject:someNSValueTopRight];
[someNSMutableArray addObject:someNSValueBottomLeft];
[someNSMutableArray addObject:someNSValueBottomRight];
```

And I want to check if distance between last two points is bigger than *something*. And if yes, I want to add some points between them. So I tried do it like this:

```
    NSValue *someNSValueForLastNSValueTopLeft = [someNSMutableArray objectAtIndex:([someNSMutableArray count]-4)];
    CGPoint lastTopLeftQuadPoint = someNSValueForLastNSValueTopLeft.pointValue;
    int distx = (quadTopLeftCorner.x - lastTopLeftQuadPoint.x) * (quadTopLeftCorner.x - lastTopLeftQuadPoint.x);
    int disty = (quadTopLeftCorner.y - lastTopLeftQuadPoint.y) * (quadTopLeftCorner.y - lastTopLeftQuadPoint.y);
    int dist = sqrtf(distx + disty);
    
    if (dist > someFloatValue) {

        someNewPointForTopLeft.x = ((quadTopLeftCorner.x + lastTopLeftQuadPoint.x)/2);
        someNewPointForTopLeft.y = ((quadTopLeftCorner.y + lastTopLeftQuadPoint.y)/2);
        someNewPointForTopRight.x = someNewPointForTopLeft.x + someFloatValue;
        someNewPointForTopRight.y = someNewPointForTopLeft.y;
        someNewPointForBottomRight.x = someNewPointForTopLeft.x + someFloatValue;
        someNewPointForBottomRight.y = someNewPointForTopLeft.y - someFloatValue;
        someNewPointForBottomLeft.x = someNewPointForTopLeft.x;
        someNewPointForBottomLeft.y = someNewPointForTopLeft.y - someFloatValue;

        someNSValueTopLeft = [NSValue valueWithPoint:someNewPointForTopLeft];
        [vertices addObject:someNSValueTopLeft];
        someNSValueTopRight = [NSValue valueWithPoint:someNewPointForTopRight];
        [vertices addObject:someNSValueTopRight];
        someNSValueBottomLeft = [NSValue valueWithPoint:someNewPointForBottomRight];
        [vertices addObject:someNSValueBottomLeft];
        someNSValueBottomRight = [NSValue valueWithPoint:someNewPointForBottomLeft];
        [vertices addObject:someNSValueBottomRight];
    }
```

But it doesn't works. Anyone could suggest me some different way?

---

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is the effect?

I just note that there are two bugs:

- calculating the distance
- the dimension of quad

The distance code has some errors, try this:

```
int distx = (quadTopLeftCorner.x - lastTopLeftQuadPoint.x) * (quadTopLeftCorner.x -lastTopLeftQuadPoint.x);        
int disty = (quadTopLeftCorner.y- lastTopLeftQuadPoint.y) * (quadTopLeftCorner.y - lastTopLeftQuadPoint.y);        
int dist = sqrtf(distx + disty);
```

Also you need to multiple two time the someFloatValue if you compose the quad from top-left corner:

```
someNewPointForTopLeft.x = ((quadTopLeftCorner.x + lastTopLeftQuadPoint.x)/2);         
someNewPointForTopLeft.y = ((quadTopLeftCorner.y + lastTopLeftQuadPoint.y)/2); 

someNewPointForTopRight.x = someNewPointForTopLeft.x + someFloatValue*2;         
someNewPointForTopRight.y = someNewPointForTopLeft.y;         

someNewPointForBottomRight.x = someNewPointForTopLeft.x + someFloatValue*2;         
someNewPointForBottomRight.y = someNewPointForTopLeft.y - someFloatValue*2;  

someNewPointForBottomLeft.x = someNewPointForTopLeft.x;         
someNewPointForBottomLeft.y = someNewPointForTopLeft.y - someFloatValue*2;
```

Anyway, to improve code and future managements I suggest to change you code introducing a Vector library and make a code like this:

```
Vector a = lastPoint;
Vector b = currentPoint;
Vector newPointForQuad=lastPoint;

if ( (lastPoint-currentPoint).dist()> someDistanceValue) newPointForQuad = (lastPoint + currentPoint)/2;

Quad quad = makeQuadAroundPoint(newPointForQuad, someQuadSize);
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you for help. About calculating distance i just made that mistake by writing code to stackOverFlow. But about second issue i will try it just right now :)

Comment: Still the same result. I have added the photo of current result

Comment: you need to calculate the new quad starting from the center of it: 'someNewPointForTopLeft.x = ((quadTopLeftCorner.x + lastTopLeftQuadPoint.x)/2)+someFloatValue; someNewPointForTopLeft.y = ((quadTopLeftCorner.y + lastTopLeftQuadPoint.y)/2)-someFloatValue;'

Comment: There is no matter where from I will start to calculate it. Its just simple math, it doesn't affect anything. There is no matter for OpenGL how coordinates for vertexes where received.

Comment: Thank you for help. Its just some maths issue. Somewhere in calculation I made mistake